# How to get the URL of an attachment in a message

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to get the URL of any attachments in a message. I can't seem to find a way to do this: whenever I try to run `console.log(message.attachments.url)`, it just outputs `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried reading the docs and other Stack Overflow questions but nothing worked.

I expect the output to be a URL of the attachment, i.e. `'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/serverid/channelid/file.png'` However, it just outputs `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.attachments` is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) (a Map with additional Utility functions) so you either have to get the specific attachment via `message.attachments.get('ID')` or if you are sure that the message only has one attachment you can use `message.attachments.first()`. Otherwise you have to iterate through the Collection via

```js
message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
  // do something with the attachment
  const url = attachment.url;
});
```

I linked to the Collection docs of Discord.js. You also have access to the typical [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) functions as well.